# My HTC One X seems to be self destructing after Jelly Bean update

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, htc-one-x

I upgraded to Jelly Bean on my AT&T HTC One X last month, and ever since then it's like my phone has just given up on life.

I had to upgrade through the installer package from the HTC Website and was walked through the process by HTC tech support.

Things that have been happening:

- **HD Widgets** would stop working off and on, the widgets I've had on the screen would simply disappear
- **Tasker** crashes constantly and profiles don't work. I have used this app on my last 2 phones as well as on the HTC One X since I got it back in Nov.
- **Swype** is no longer my keyboard and no matter what I do I can't seem to get it back.
- *most importantly* : My microphone quit working on phone calls. It still works on speakerphone, but no longer works normalls.
- *Other various weird happenings here and there*. I swear it's like my phone is haunted or has become sentient and given up on life.

These are all apps I have used for a very long time and have never had issues with. At least 2 of them are very popular and respectable apps.
(I would link to them, but Google Play is unfortunately blocked at work)

My phone is **not** rooted. I have not dropped my phone in water or even dropped it on the ground. Literally nothing major has changed in the past 2-3 months except the Jelly Bean update about a month ago.

If you need any more information to help me get pointed in the right direction to resolve my issues, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those problems started right away after the update: did the update process include a factory-reset? If not (and nothing else helps), this might be your chance:

Backup all things you can backup (luckily on JB that's not too big an issue, see [Full Backup of non-rooted devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28296/16575) -- but I recommend to have all your apps into separate packages, as otherwise a full restore might bring back your problems). Then do a factory-reset.

Before restoring anything, check if your problems are gone. Then restore your apps one-by-one (just to make sure to not bring back the problem).

As for the backup process: check with [Helium - App Sync and Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.backup), this is the easiest way to go. You can mark all your apps, make sure to check that `.apk` files are included (by default, *Helium* only backups data), and give it a go. *Helium* creates separate backup archives per-app, so you can restore them separately. Make a copy of the backup folder to your PC, just in case -- if restoring via *Helium* should fail for any reason, this still gives you the chance to use `adb restore` via USB.

**Background:** It might very well be that some settings got messed up on update. A [factory-reset](/questions/tagged/factory-reset) will erase all your apps and data, plus the Dalvik-Cache (optimized app code -- this might be the culprit if it doesn't 100% match the new Android version), so all settings revert to "default". Your Android system ROM (JellyBean) will not be reverted to what you had before, so no worries for that :)

Comment: No it did not. I was actually expecting it to be reset and backed up all my important information multiple times before I updated to Jelly Bean, but the apps simply weren't installed but still completely there in the folder structure. 

I'm not too worried about the apps themselves, I can re-install them from the Play store. 

I will try this tonight, thanks much.

Comment: That description makes a "system confusion" even more likely, while at the same time it seems a factory-reset will really be the remedy to that. As you already have everything backed up, go for it -- I keep my fingers crossed meanwhile and wait for your feedback :) Good luck!

Comment: Glad to read -- and thanks for your feedback!