# how to survive a program from factory reset

Tags: factory-reset

I want to that a program / software like facebook/gmail/ or any game will survive after factory reset with its configuration as before reset means email id password automatically configured after reset. any suggestion please?

Answer (score 4):

Preserving the application itself (APK) can be easily achieved (with root access) by dropping the .apk in /system/app, but the configurations are a bit trickier to keep.

Factory resets generally do a wipe of /data, which also contains all the configs/gamesaves/etc that all apps installed have, so you might have to use a seperate backup app (I recommend Titanium Backup) for that.

Answer (score 1):

As [aureljared already pointed out](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/75528/16575), a factory-rest wipes the `/data` permission, so you cannot simply "exclude" and app *and its data* from being "removed". However, you can backup it beforehand, and restore it afterwards.

Easiest way (not requiring root) is utilizing `adb backup` for this. It will require the ADB tools installed on your computer<sup>1</sup>, and [usb-debugging](/questions/tagged/usb-debugging) turned on on your device, but that's it. Then you can either deal with it directly from your computer (with the device attached via USB), or use a tool like [Helium - App Sync and Backup](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.koushikdutta.backup) directly on your device (after initializing it via your computer, if your device is not rooted) to backup and restore all or selected apps.<sup>2</sup>

---

**<sup>1</sup>** See [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/16575) and our [adb tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info)
**<sup>2</sup>** See my answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/45979/16575) and [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/75213/16575) for details